Extract fillable PDF form fields data
I have a fillable PDF form with a lot of fields on it.  I need to extract the answers to 8 of the fields to use in Google sheets. Is there an option to do this without uploading the PDF to an external site.  The PDF contains very sensitive data.  It would be ideal if I could click a button on the PDF and send (using export or submit a form) the 8 non-sensitive fields that I need to a server or existing spreadsheet to use.
I am open to having developers create an app/code to do this.
